# Mongo: Finding from multiple queries

Tags: php, mongodb

New to Mongo here. I'm using the PHP lib and trying to work out how I can find in a collection from multiple queries. I could do this by repeating the query with a different query, but I wondered if it can be done in one.

I.e.

```
$idsToLookFor = array(2124,4241,5553);
$query = $db->thisCollection->find(array('id' => $idsToLookFor));
```

That's what I'd like to do. However it doesn't work. What I'm trying to do is find a set of results for all the id's at one time.

Possible or just do a findOne on each with a foreach/for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$in Operator`

```
$idsToLookFor = array(2124,4241,5553);
$query = $db->thisCollection->find(array(
    'id' => array('$in' => $idsToLookFor)
));
```